# What to do when Win 7 x64 installer doesn't recognize HD

Tags: windows-7, drivers, installation, sata, 64-bit

A friend of mine is having a huge problem with his new PC. He wants to install Windows 7 x64 but the installer doesn't find his Hard Discs. The discs are connected via SATA on a **Asus P6T SE** motherboard.

I think the problem is just that there is no driver available for the SATA-Controller and thus no discs are found. Yesterday we looked up the available downloads on the [Asus Page](http://www.asus.de/product.aspx?P_ID=t4yhK6y9W9o7iQ9E&templete=2) and downloaded two drivers we thought that fix the problem. We put those drivers on a USB and told the installer to look there for additional drivers. But it didn't help.

I am not sure if it would work, but if he would have an internet-connection via LAN-cable would the installer be able to lookup additional drivers automatically or does he have to provide those manually?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve the problem yesterday and I have to admit, without a lack of communication it would have been solved earlier :)

After my friend told me that the Vista-Installer was once able to find the disk I was thinking that the controller or the disk might be broken. To check this I booted his machine with a Linux Live-CD to see if this is able to find the disk or if it is broken. But Linux was able to see the disk and I was able to create files on it. For an additional check I started the Linux Partitioner (KDE) and there I could only see the disk (sda) but no partition (sda1). After creating a FAT partition and rebooting, the Win7 installer could find the disk. I deleted the FAT partition, created new NTFS ones and all went fine.

**So obviously the problem was a broken partition table and not the driver :)**

Comment: Wow kind of weird issue... Glad you finally revolved it :)

Answer (score 2):

This question should be moved to SuperUser...

Anyway, You have to do it manually, you're on the right way by using a USB Key to load driver.

Try these : http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/sata/IMSM_V8901023_Windows7.zip

Of course the files should be extracted from the setup file on your USB drive so that windows are able to read it...

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the file, but I cannot unpack the files any further. I tried the cab files as well as the setup files. I also tried to unpack with cabextract and unshield which are linux-tools for that purpose. On Windows I tried WinRar, but none of the tools could read it. I tried to install the drivers on my system so I have access to them, but the installer canceled because of my different system.

Comment: Ok, there's the real deal, at least it should be this : http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3061&DwnldID=17884&lang=eng extract them to the USB Drive and then try to load them in windows setup, should work :P

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it was something else (see solution post)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to disable AHCI in the BIOS?

you can install Windows 7 in IDE mode and later change the settings to AHCI.

for more information see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/94223/howto-enable-ahci-mode-after-windows-vista-install-in-ide-mode-and-before-for-win/94417#94417).