# Switching from RAID to AHCI with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, raid, ahci

Many tutorials explaining how to change from one mode to the other. Usually it revolves around these instructions:

Change: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci` `Start` to `0`
Change: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\iaStorA` `Start` to `0`

`Start = 0` tells Windows to load the driver during boot. **By the way: `MSAHCI` is now `storahci` in Windows 8**.

I installed Windows in RAID mode. Because the RAID manager always pops up during boot and I don't use RAID anyways I want to **switch to AHCI**.

I thought I could do that by setting the startup mode of `iaStorA` to manual (`Start=3`), but then I receive a BSOD after changing the mode in BIOS. When just leaving them like they are (both services at `0`) and switching to AHCI in BIOS (from RAID) I also receive the BSOD.
I can always switch back to RAID with no problem, but I would love to switch to AHCI. Any steps I'm missing?

Comment: An answer to this question might help you: http://superuser.com/questions/471102/change-from-ide-to-ahci-after-installing-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound Perfect, http://superuser.com/a/471108/28451 answers my question.

Comment: @moontear - I thought it might.

Comment: Maybe you want to add an answer with the information? I don't want to delete this question as it adds some more information for further searches of other users.