# How does SSD Wear Leveling work?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

Is ssd wear leveling built into the hardware or the software? Does ide mode (since I cloned my data from a hdd with ide mode, I cannot set it to ahci because it results in a BSOD) have any disadvantages in terms of the longevity of the drive (does it not allow for wear leveling).

The ssd is an intel series 335 with 250 gigs of storage

Comment: It's functionality implemented in software/firmware not hardware. But it's an integral feature of the device so it really doesn't matter. Wear leveling should be performed regardless/independently of IDE or AHCI mode selection.

Comment: wrt AHCI vs IDE, have you tried http://superuser.com/q/471102/47108?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller mode has no effect on wear leveling. It will, however, affect trim.

Comment: So is wear leveling software or on the controller of the ssd? Also, isnt trim a software feature specific to the os?

Comment: Wear leveling is usually software on the controller of the SSD. Trim is a software feature specific to the OS, but you can't issue a trim if the link to the drive doesn't support it.

Comment: Ok. So software on the controller = on the actual drive. If the link to my drive is sata, but it is in "ide mode" and my os supports trim (windows 7), would there still be trim? And does the lack of trim hurt the drive or just hurt performance?

Comment: @agz There will be no trim if the link is in IDE mode. It will not hurt a modern drive in a way you are likely to be able to measure, but it will hurt performance.