# SSD connected to ASRock Z77 Extreme4 motherboard not detected by Windows setup

Tags: windows, motherboard, windows-installation, hardware-detection

Just built a new PC today and used the AsRock Z77 Motherboard. I haven't built a new PC in a long time, probably XP days. Went to install Windows 8.1 from a USB disk and Windows is telling me it cannot find my hard drives, even though they are listed in the BIOS.

I am using a SSD Samsung 850 EVO SATA drive with default BIOS settings. Any help at this point? I have tried my USB disk in all USB ports and tried Win7, still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch to IDE mode in the BIOS, then install Windows 8.
2. Edit the registry as instructed [here](https://superuser.com/a/471108/138343), reboot and switch back to AHCI in the BIOS.

Additionally ensure all the latest drivers from AsRock are installed and the BIOS is up to date.