# How to change Sata controller settings to avoid a blue screen? Windows 8

Tags: windows, ssd, sata, controller

How to go from AHCI to IDE just for firmware flashing on my SSD.
Currently using windows 8.
Tried a few times but kept getting the dreaded blue screen.

Comment: There are lots of questions about enabling AHCI after installing Windows, such as [this](http://superuser.com/questions/94223/how-can-i-enable-ahci-mode-after-windows-vista-install-in-ide-mode-and-before-fo) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/110927/enabling-ahci-on-sata-drive-in-windows-7). Also check the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976). You can do the opposite to revert to IDE. AFAIK nothing about the procedure's changed in Win8.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to switch to the Legacy/IDE mode just for the firmware upgrade - the trick is not to let Windows boot up while in this mode. Most SSD firmware updates come as a bootable .iso images with their own flashers integrated anyway.

So

1. switch BIOS setting to IDE
2. flash
3. switch BIOS back to AHCI
4. boot into Windows